# Can't select "migrate to" destination when browsing on Android phone

Tags: bug, vote-to-close, mobile-web

I carry out some moderation tasks from my Android phone - using the standard browser, but the one that I can't seem to do is migrate questions.

When I enter information in the destination box, for example "StackOverflow" the autocomplete returns **meta StackOverflow** and **StackOverflow** as you would expect, but instead of two links, I just get one link hotspot which encompasses the two but actually links to the second of the two items.

This is fine if I wanted to migrate a question to Stack Overflow, but when I want to migrate to Cryptography, the link points to their meta instead - it looks like the link is always to the second one, so as they are alphabetically ordered this problem mostly affects sites before M in the alphabet.

**Update** August 2013 - this is still an issue on Android phones. I have now tested on two HTC phones and a Samsung Glaxy SIII.

Comment: What browser? Can you see JS errors?

Comment: This is with the stock browser on Android 4.1 and 4.2. No errors reported.