# migrating question using android doesn't clear placeholder field

Tags: bug, status-completed, migration, moderator-tools, accessibility

When using an android phone (in this case my HTC One running android 4.3 and Chrome browser) whenever I need to migrate a question I can select the 'Migration' option but can't clear all the placeholder text. It just adds itself back in when i've cleared it out.

Selecting the field makes the `'type to search'` text selectable. Should I clear it out and then start typing in there the `'type to search'` text adds back into the field next to where i've typed. So in effect I end up with `'stack overflowtype to search'` showing in the field that I then have to move the cursor to the end of the text and delete the supplementary text.

[image]

Now this is annoying.

It would be annoying if it were on a desktop where I have a mouse to help me, but with my fingers jabbing at a text cursor in a small field several times it drives me crazy.

So my suggestion is - **Please remove the placeholder**. There isn't really a Label on that field anyway, so for accessibility purposes there really should be one. So perhaps set 'Type to Search for a Stack Exchange Site' as the field label.

Or just scrap the placeholder anyway. People with the rep to do a migration should know how these sites work anyway, so it's arguable that it's redundant text anyway. But I suggest having it as a proper form label instead.

Note, I've seen this post (below) but it doesn't seem to be the same issue that I have.

[Can't select "migrate to" destination when browsing on Android phone](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/142645/cant-select-migrate-to-destination-when-browsing-on-android-phone)

Comment: What browser exactly are you using? Sounds like the browser is not supporting HTML 5.

Comment: It's the Chrome browser on the phone, which does support HTML5 . I don't think the placeholder itself is an actual html5 `placeholder`, I think it's using JavaScript or something (can't really tell as the whole modal popup doesn't work without JS so I can't test that easily as I can't even access it without script). And there are some `blur` effects going on too.

Comment: That's weird... if they have custom placeholder I agree it should be removed or replaced with standard HTML 5. By the way, this is moderator only tool, adding proper tag.

Comment: @ShadowWizard yeah, that's why I tagged this 'accessibility' too as it's not really ideal the way it's been put together.

Answer (score 1):

Since this is a moderator tools (IE9- compatibility is not a big concern in that case)  I've replaced the JS fiddlery with a html5 placeholder. The fix will be with you in build rev `2014.3.28.2099` on meta and `2014.3.28.1498` on sites.

Comment: Ah, great. I look forward to migrating unsuitable questions to the wrong sites from my phone with ease then!