# 'Duplicate question' input has a placeholder problem

Tags: bug, close-dialog, safari

While voting to close a question as a duplicate (though admittedly I made a bad choice in the chosen duplicate) I pasted a URL into the text-input, which started out as:

[image]

And, after pasting the URL, looked like this:

[image]

Note the confusing combination of pale-grey pasted-text over the darker placeholder-text. In terms of UI it's *not awesome*.

Of course triggering a key-based event (even a white space) removes the placeholder and properly colours the pasted text; but it seems like an overlooked error, perhaps in the event-handling (or possibly just in iOS Safari's interpretation/application of events).

This takes place only on iOS 7/iPad Air so far as I can tell, though I've tested Android KitKat on Nexus 5 and 7 also.

Comment: Now if they just used HTML5's `placeholder` attribute the whole stupid problem would go away.

Comment: Same root cause as the one here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/215118/migrating-question-using-android-doesnt-clear-placeholder-field (not dupe though as that one is about a moderator only option)

Comment: I opened this question to moan in a comment about the lack of `placeholder` attributes, but on closer inspection realised I'd beaten myself to it by almost a month.